# Android app cannot be updated in Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-update-app

I tried to update my app at play Store but received the following msg

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a differentcertificate to your previous APKs.
>
> You must use the same certificate.
>   Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with
>   fingerprint(s):

I've do some search here and google. Results are mainly talking about using wrong keystore, key invalid or key is outdated.

So, I do the following

1. Download the published apk from google play console
2. keytool -list -printcert -jarfile published.apk
3. keytool -list -keystore /xxx/xxx/xxx.keystore

Potential problem
1. Using wrong keystore ／ key
2. Key expired

Fingerprint from published.apk and the xxx.keystore are match
Valid date of apk till 2044

Both potential problem 1 and 2 should not be a problem now.

Any idea? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the wrong key store file for your APK? I mean the same key store file that you were using in past for the same App?

Comment: Hi, I've applied  keytool -list -printcert -jarfile to the app I published and the app newly generated, the fingerprint is the same